# How to remove button style in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile with asp.net.

In my project I want to show button text. when i make a grid with three column, the buttons are fit to the mobile. But Buttons are not show the text in vertical position of mobile. Its show in horizontal position.

```
 <div id="body" class="ui-content ui-body-a" > <%----%>
            <div class="ui-grid-b">                
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>             
                <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="btnUp" runat="server" Text="UP" onclick="btnUp_Click" /></div>    
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"> <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>                       
                <div class="ui-block-c"><asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="DOWN" onclick="btnDown_Click" /></div>     
            </div>
</div>
```

Buttons are show like below.

```
 ________   ________   ________
(___B1___) (___B2___) (___B3___)

 _____   _____   _____
(_____) (_____) (_____)
```

I am using

```
 <link href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For jquery Mobile.

Help me.

**Updated Question -**

I am not bother about vertical and horizontal. In my project button text not fully visible. That means,. See the below image and code, This is an example,.. from [here](http://mobile-web-app.blogspot.in/2011/12/apply-grid-layout-on-jquery-mobile.html)

In this did you see arrow-l, arrow-r in image. It will show a... ,.. and a,.. like this.

For the same,.. my project not show this one char also,..

Did you understand my problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, height = device-height" />
<title>jQuery Mobile:  Button Icon</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header">
 <h1>Grid Layout</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div class="ui-grid-b">
 <div class="ui-block-a">
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" >arrow-l</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" >arrow-r</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" >arrow-u</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" >arrow-d</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" >delete</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="plus" >plus</a>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-block-b">
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="minus" >minus</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="check" >check</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="gear" >gear</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" >refresh</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="forward" >forward</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="back" >back</a>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-block-c">
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="grid" >grid</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="star" >star</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="alert" >alert</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="info" >info</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="home" >home</a>
  <a data-role="button" data-icon="search" >search</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
 <h4><a href="http://mobile-web-app.blogspot.com/">http://mobile-web-app.blogspot.com/</a></h4>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: its clearly showing that it cannot fit 3 buttons. Is it mandatory that you should have 3 buttons? you can use `drop downlist`  or some alternative instead of so many buttons on a screen right? To be honest & not offensive, As a design perspective its really a bad design. I would recommend you to take some time off designing the Layout before you code it. :)

Comment: @Dave Ok sir. I will see alternative.

Comment: I see you are developing for `android` but the good place to read is [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) A Great Resource to understand **the importance of design in mobile apps.**

Answer (score 0):

use `<li>`  inside `<ul>`tags for each of the button then they will be shown in vertical way.
Something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="ui-block-a"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="ui-block-b"> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: I don't know why you are using div's for each button (thinking that it might have some underlying functionality, which I'm not bothering as of now. Hence keeping your code the same inside the `li` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the padding on those buttons, or remove the ellipsis entirely with a

```
white-space: normal;
```

CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to control button multiple line display,

```
.ui-btn-inner { 
    white-space: normal !important; 
}
```

Display result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the stylesheet you are using:

```
.ui-btn-text { white-space:normal !important; }
```

This should take care of it.